# Specflow generated feature.cs file is not getting updated

Tags: c#, automated-tests, visual-studio-2019, bdd, specflow

When I make changes in Specflow feature file, its not updating feature.cs file automatically and getting an error [Specflow] System.Unauthorized.Access.Exception

I am using Specflow version 3.1.97 in Visual studio 2019 and below is the configuration of Specflow extension

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since SpecFlow 3, you can't anymore use the SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator.

You have to use the MSBuild integration to generate the code-behind files.
But this is easy. You have simply to add the `SpecFlow.Tools.MSBuild.Generation` NuGet package to your project.
If you still have configured a custom tool for your feature files, you have to remove this.

You can find more information here: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Tools/Generate-Tests-From-MsBuild.html

Answer (score 0):

After above solution, I was getting an error shown in below screen capture.

[image]

The reason behind this error was my project was linked to TFS and feature.cs file was not updated as it was at lock state.

[image]

When that file was check out for edit, feature.cs file was getting updated automatically.